# Bounding mixed derivatives by Laplacian ($L^\infty$ regularity estimate)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $u\colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is twice-differentiable and 1-periodic along each axis. Can the maximum norm of the Hessian be controlled by the maximum norm of the Laplacian, i.e. does there exists $C$ such that
$$
\|D^2u\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \|\Delta u\|_{L^\infty}.
$$
I am confused because

- theorems 4.1 and 5.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4450) suggest that this follows from standard elliptic regularity theory,
- but [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404739/mixed-derivative-bounded-by-laplacian-in-2d) seems to suggest that the result is not correct.